# Angular 2 native view encapsulation

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, shadow-dom

There is already [an answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651993/diff-between-viewencapsulation-native-viewencapsulation-none-and-viewencapsulat) that explains the difference between `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`, `ViewEncapsulation.Native` ad `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Let's say there is Electron application that is guaranteed to be bundled with Chromium version that natively supports shadow DOM and `ViewEncapsulation.Native`. How can this case benefit from native encapsulation to avoid emulation overhead?

Another possible case is debugging views in Angular 2 application that are heavily cluttered with helper attributes and namespaced CSS classes due to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`.

Can default encapsulation be changed to `ViewEncapsulation.Native` globally for all components that don't specify `encapsulation`?

What are the other practical appliances of `ViewEncapsulation.Native`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7883 this should work

```
import {CompilerConfig} from '@angular/compiler';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [{
  provide: CompilerConfig,
  useValue: new CompilerConfig({defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native})
}])
```

I haven't tried it myself yet though.

I guess `ViewEncapsulation.Native` will be mostly beneficial where one targets Chrome only. It seems it will still take quite some time until other browsers release their shadow DOM support.

The main benefit is that Angular2 doesn't need to add attributes to each component element and that not all component styles need to be added to `<head>` anymore.

Performance won't be much of an issue in most cases with `Emulated` when the Offline Template Compiler is used.

Comment: There was a syntactic error, but otherwise it is working. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for fixing :) and for the feedback.